# List modification in a loop

Tags: python

*I'm a newcomer to Python but I understand that things should not be done this way, so please consider the following code snippets as purely educational :-)*

I'm currently reading 'Learning Python' and trying to fully understand the following example:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for x in L:
...    x += 1
...
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I did not understand if this behavior was somewhat related to the immutability of the numeric types, so I've run the following test:

```
>>> L = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
>>> for x in L:
...    x += ['_']
...
>>> L
[[1, '_'], [2, '_'], [3, '_'], [4, '_'], [5, '_']]
```

**Question: what makes the list unchanged in the first code and changed in the second ?**

My intuition is that the syntax is misleading and that:

- `x += 1` for an integer really means `x = x + 1` (thus assigning a new reference)
- `x += ['_']` for a list really means `x.extend('_')` (thus changing the list in place)

Comment: your intuition is correct

Comment: and for completeness, the "correct" way to do this is `[x+1 for x in L]`

Comment: @Kimvais: that assumes you want to create a new list.

Comment: `L = [x+1 for x in L]` if you don't want a new list, then :)

Comment: @Kimvais: That still creates a new list, it's just setting `L` to refer to the new list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Question: what makes the list unchanged in the first code and changed in the second ?*

In the first code, the list is a sequence of (immutable) integers. The loop sets `x` to refer to each element of the sequence in turn. `x += 1` changes `x` to refer to a different integer that is one more than the value `x` previously referred to. The element in the original list is unchanged.

In the second code, the list if a sequence of (mutable) lists. The loop sets `x` to refer to each element of the sequence in turn. `x += ['_']` as `x` refers to a list, this extends the list referred to by `x` with `['_']`.

Comment: So it's really the immutability of the integer that explains it than, thanks !